# Default request parameter values inside POJO

Tags: java, spring, rest, serialization

I've a POJO `UserRequest`, with some fields having default values :

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class UserRequest {
  String username;
  @Builder.Default
  String source =  "app";
  @Builder.Default
  Locale locale = Locale.US;
}
```

and controller with POJO as *GET* request parameter:

```java
@GetMapping("/getDescription")
public List<String> getDescription(UserRequest userRequest,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "descriptionType" , defaultValue = "DEFAULT") DescriptionType descriptionType {
      return Something.process(userRequest, descriptionType);
}
```

My request parameters properly get converted into `userRequest` object.

My issue is, default values don't make their way into the `userRequest` object when parameter are absent. They remain null.

E.g. my request

- `host/getDescription?username=test_username&source=app&locale=en_US` , completely populates `userRequest` object
- `host/getDescription?username=test_username` , has `userRequest` object's fields source and locale null.

From my understanding when the parameter is missing in the request, it should honour the default value.

What am I missing? Is there anyway of getting this to work without manually doing this in setters?

Here's what I have tried so far :

- I guessed Spring uses Jackson to do the conversion, so I tried adding `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`
- I tried adding `@ModelAttribute` to the controller parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was being caused due to a known bug in Lombok's `Builder.default`. See : https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1347

Removing the annotation, or creating a custom NoArgsConstructor works.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html).

ex. https://sdqali.in/blog/2016/01/30/using-custom-arguments-in-spring-mvc-controllers/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. But do you know what's wrong in the existing approach? Is it not achievable without implementing `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`?

Comment: I think the way you want is the same as [`PageableArgumentResolver`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PageableArgumentResolver.java)